# failed to bind shortcut under gnome-do to Super + Space ( Unity on Ubuntu 16.10 )

Tags: unity, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz

When I try to bind Super + Space to gnome-do launcher under Unity on Ubuntu 16.10 after changing the Dash key to <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, I get a pop up with an error saying "failed to bind shortcut".

Strange thing is that if I try to bind the same key combo to Dash in Compiz Config Settings Manager, it works fine without displaying any information that the shortcut has been taken.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is being caused by the keyboard layout switcher which is hugging the <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut.

[image]

The "En" icon.

Settings of this app can be found in System Setting -> Text Entry

[image]

and can be easily changed to for e.g. Ctrl + Super + Space to release the needed shortcut.

[image]

After this adjustment Gnome-Do will be able to takeover the Super + Space shortcut